# Sed & Regex: match between two characters only sometimes successful

Tags: regex, linux, sed

When I execute the command

```
echo '<test>' | sed -e 's/<\(.*\)>/\1/g'
```

I get the string

```
test
```

returned. When I execute the command

```
echo 'Jun 10 13:23:16 server /opt/app/introdedaemon/sbin/mq2init[14150]: Debug 1433935396.995245: (XMLRPCConnector.cpp)(MQMessage)(98)[domt initrode.om]: encoded string: <aGVyZSBpcyBub3RoaW5n c3RpbGwgbm90aGluZw== > (size 908)' | sed -e 's/<\(.*\)>/\1/g'
```

I would **expect** to get the string

```
aGVyZSBpcyBub3RoaW5n c3RpbGwgbm90aGluZw==
```

returned, but **instead** I get the string

```
Jun 10 13:23:16 server /opt/app/introdedaemon/sbin/mq2init[14150]: Debug 1433935396.995245: (XMLRPCConnector.cpp)(MQMessage)(98)[domt initrode.om]: encoded string: aGVyZSBpcyBub3RoaW5n c3RpbGwgbm90aGluZw==  (size 908)
```

back. **Why does this happen** and w**ith which regex can I return the part between the "<" and ">"** for the string

```
Jun 10 13:23:16 server /opt/app/introdedaemon/sbin/mq2init[14150]: Debug 1433935396.995245: (XMLRPCConnector.cpp)(MQMessage)(98)[domt initrode.om]: encoded string: <aGVyZSBpcyBub3RoaW5n c3RpbGwgbm90aGluZw== > (size 908)
```

?

Comment: The tool you are looking for is perhaps `grep`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
sed 's/.*<\(.*\)>.*/\1/'
```

as there is a text before `<` and after `>` also.

This will give output as:

```
aGVyZSBpcyBub3RoaW5n c3RpbGwgbm90aGluZw==
```

You can get **same output** using this much simpler `awk` command also:

```
awk -F '[<>]' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: I would have suggested `grep -oP '<\K[^>]*'`, but I suppose there are many ways to skin a cat.